# Firebase Database Get All Value In Order Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, request

I develop for Firebase Cloud Functions. I have a Firebase Realtime Database like this:

```
----- myData 
      -------eqewrwrepere (this one is a device token)
                         ---------Lta+sde-fer (this one is a firebase id)
                                  firstvalue  : "a"
                                  secondvalue : "b"

                        ----------Qrgd+ad-qdda (this one is second firebase id)
                                  firstvalue  : "c"
                                  secondvalue : "d"

      -------eqwerSAsdqe (this one is another device token)
                        ---------Lta+sde-fer (this one is a firebase id)
                                 firstvalue  : "x"
                                 secondvalue : "y"

                       ----------Qrgd+ad-qdda (this one is second firebase id)
                                 firstvalue  : "z"
                                 secondvalue : "t"
```

I fetch these data by this code.  With this code i fetch all data and put them an array. And when fetching done, i loop this array for finding items. I am an iOS developer, so i am a newbie for NodeJS. Here is what i want to do:

1. Get `firstvalue` for each database data.
2. Make a api request with firstvalue of each database data.
3. Api returns an image.
4. Write image temp directory.
5. Process this image for visionApi.
6. Extract text.
7. Update database.
8. Send notification for deviceToken

Now i am able to retrieve database items in my array. When i make a request in for loop, request called async. So for loop continues, but request response or writing file and vision processing executed only once.

In for loop, get databasearray[0], make request, write file, process it with vision api, update database and go for next databasearray[1] item.

I read about `Promises` on different pages. But i did not understand.

Thank you.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
//var fs = require("fs");
// Get a reference to the Cloud Vision API component
const Vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const vision = new Vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
//const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
var fs = require("fs");
var os = require("os");
var databaseArray = [];


exports.hourly_job = functions.pubsub
.topic('hourly-job')
.onPublish((event) => {
    console.log("Hourly Job");


    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("myData")


    ref.once("value").then(function(allData) {

        allData.forEach(function(deviceToken) {

            deviceToken.forEach(function(firebaseIDs) {

                var deviceTokenVar = deviceToken.key;
                var firebaseIDVar = firebaseIDs.key;
                var firstvalue = firebaseIDs.child("firstvalue").val();
                var secondvalue = firebaseIDs.child("secondvalue").val();


                var items = [deviceTokenVar, firebaseIDVar, firstvalue, secondvalue];

                databaseArray.push([...items]);


            });

        });
        return databaseArray;
    }).then(function(databasem) {

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < databaseArray.length; i++) {

            var databaseArrayDeviceToken = databaseArray[i][0];
            console.log("DeviceToken: " + databaseArrayDeviceToken);

            var databaseArrayFirebaseID = databaseArray[i][1];
            console.log("FirebaseID: " + databaseArrayFirebaseID);

            var databaseArrayfirstvalue = databaseArray[i][2];
            console.log("firstval: " + databaseArrayfirstvalue);

            var databaseArraysecondval = databaseArray[i][3];
            console.log("Second: " + databaseArraysecondval);


            var url = "http://api.blabla" + databaseArrayfirstvalue;

            /////////////here make a request, pause loop, process returned image, but how //////////////////////         
            request.get({
                    url: url,
                    encoding: 'binary'
                }, function(error, httpResponse, body) {


                    if (!error && httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {

                        fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/processed.jpg', body, 'binary')
                        console.log("file written");
                    })

            }

        });

        return true;
    });
```

Comment: If it was me, I would switch to TypeScript and use Async/Await. Those .then() are really bad

Comment: Please explain your answer. How can i write TypeScript? I am purely newbie :)

Comment: follow this series, very useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&list=PLZeWHHIL3TFSjCNu9lxNCkc6qnn3j6n3O

Comment: I watch videos with your suggestion. But i did not understand. So sorry :(

Comment: Just found that js supports async/await. please read this https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/

Comment: Compare the section "Solution 1: The .then Christmas tree" with section "By using async/await our problems are magically gone"

Comment: Wow!  I got the solution with your help. I post my solution in answer section. But now I have different problems. For-loop wait for response with await, but sometimes it hangs on one step. And sometimes for loop function called more than one. I don’t understand it. I write them on answer section. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark my comment as useful by clicking the up triangle. Post another question with your problem

Comment: I updated my answer with the code. Please take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution with Mocas helps. Here is the solution. I use async/await functions in code. Now for loop waits for the function response. But now I have different problems. I think main async function hangs because of awaits. And then next hourly trigger, it runs again. So console log shows 15-16-17 or more ‘i’ values in for loop. I have 4 element in database array but console log shows more than this every hour. And it increases every time. So I guess that I should cancel this await functions after a timeout. But I don’t know how. Here is code:

```
    use strict';

    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
    var request = require('request-promise').defaults({ encoding: null });
    var fs = require('fs');
    // Get a reference to the Cloud Vision API component
    const Vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
    const vision = new Vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
    var os = require("os");
    var databaseArray = [];
    var uniqueFilename = require('unique-filename')

    exports.hourly_job = functions.pubsub
      .topic('hourly-job')
      .onPublish((event) => {
        console.log("Hourly Job");




        var db = admin.database();
        var ref = db.ref("myData")


       ref.once("value").then(function(allData) {

       allData.forEach(function(deviceToken) {

              deviceToken.forEach(function(firebaseIDs) {

            var deviceTokenVar = deviceToken.key;
            var firebaseIDVar = firebaseIDs.key;
            var firstvalue = firebaseIDs.child("firstvalue").val();
            var secondvalue = firebaseIDs.child("secondvalue").val();


            var items = [deviceTokenVar, firebaseIDVar, firstvalue, secondvalue];

            databaseArray.push([...items]);
            //console.log(databaseArray);   
    //return true;
    });   
    //return true;
    });
    return databaseArray;
    }).then(function (databasem) {

        main().catch(console.error);                
            });

    return true;
    });

    const main = async () => {

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < databaseArray.length; i++) {

            console.log("Database Arrays " + i + ". elements: ");


            var databaseArrayDeviceToken = databaseArray[i][0];
            console.log("DeviceToken: " + databaseArrayDeviceToken);

            var databaseArrayFirebaseID = databaseArray[i][1];
            console.log("FirebaseID: " + databaseArrayFirebaseID);

            var databaseArrayfirst = databaseArray[i][2];
            console.log("first: " + databaseArrayfirst);

            var databaseArraysecond = databaseArray[i][3];
            console.log("second: " + databaseArraysecond);



             if (databaseArrayfirst != "") {

            var apiUrl = "http://api.blabla;

            try {
            const apiBody = await request.get(apiUrl); 


        ///////////////////////////vison start//////////////////////    

            const visionResponseBody = await vision.documentTextDetection(apiBody)

             var visionResponse = visionResponseBody[0].textAnnotations[0].description;

             console.log("Vision response text " + visionResponse );

             ...some logic here about response...

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////   
             var getdatabasevar = await admin.database().ref("myData/" + databaseArrayDeviceToken + "/" + databaseArrayFirebaseID);

             await getdatabasevar.update({
             "firstvalue": visionResponse
             });  


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////  

             var getanotgerdatabasevar = await admin.database().ref("myData/" + databaseArrayDeviceToken + "/" + databaseArrayFirebaseID + "/" + "secondvalue");

             await getanotgerdatabasevar.once("value")
              .then(function(var) {

              ..some logic..


              //send notification


              });
    } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            }
    ///////////////////////////vison end//////////////////////  


        }

    };
    return true;
    };
```